# map is not ready when using hazelcast

Tags: java, hazelcast

I am using hazelcast v3.2.4 client and server.  THe server loads up data from a database - this issue does not happen with less data so I am guessing its data size related but need to confirm.  I have two nodes in the server for testing - I can add more once I know that's the issue. The map config I am using for my hazelcast maps is provided below.  I am not sure if I misconfigured the maps somehow. Errors on client and server are given below.  I am not sure if its GC or simply too much data on the node (simple top check shows memory usage of less than 35% though - I will check using jvisualvm soon)

**Error on client**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
    at com.hazelcast.map.DefaultRecordStore.checkIfLoaded(DefaultRecordStore.java:138)
    at com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation.run(MapSizeOperation.java:36)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.processOperation(BasicOperationService.java:363)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.processPacket(BasicOperationService.java:309)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.access$400(BasicOperationService.java:102)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$BasicOperationProcessorImpl.process(BasicOperationService.java:766)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$PartitionThread.process(BasicOperationScheduler.java:276)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$PartitionThread.doRun(BasicOperationScheduler.java:270)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$PartitionThread.run(BasicOperationScheduler.java:245)
    at ------ End remote and begin local stack-trace ------.(Unknown Source)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.resolveResponse(BasicInvocation.java:862)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.resolveResponseOrThrowException(BasicInvocation.java:795)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:698)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicInvocation$InvocationFuture.get(BasicInvocation.java:676)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.invokeOnPartitions(BasicOperationService.java:623)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService.invokeOnAllPartitions(BasicOperationService.java:549)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl.invokeOnAllPartitions(ClientEngineImpl.java:175)
    at com.hazelcast.client.AllPartitionsClientRequest.process(AllPartitionsClientRequest.java:29)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.processRequest(ClientEngineImpl.java:499)
    at com.hazelcast.client.ClientEngineImpl$ClientPacketProcessor.run(ClientEngineImpl.java:446)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run(PoolExecutorThreadFactory.java:59)
```

**Server**

```
2014-09-11 11:37:54,525 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@22110814, partitionId=42, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,525 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@7c6003d7, partitionId=51, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,525 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@4968024, partitionId=40, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,525 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@199a9735, partitionId=44, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,525 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@7a7827d7, partitionId=48, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,526 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@561be5e7, partitionId=53, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,526 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@33531304, partitionId=46, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,526 WARN c.h.s.i.BasicInvocation [hz._hzInstance_1_testApp.response] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:5701 [testApp] [3.2.4] Retrying invocation: BasicInvocation{ serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.operation.MapSizeOperation@66bcc8a0, partitionId=55, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=240, callTimeout=60000, target=Address[192.168.110.159]:5701}, Reason: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableHazelcastException: Map is not ready!!!
2014-09-11 11:37:54,526 WARN c.h.

  <map name="testMap">
        <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format>
        <backup-count>0</backup-count> 
        <async-backup-count>1</async-backup-count>  
        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>
        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>
        <eviction-policy>LRU</eviction-policy>
        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>
        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>
        <initial-load-mode>EAGER</initial-load-mode>
         <map-store enabled="true">
            <class-name>models.hazelcast.storeload.TestStoreLoad</class-name>
            <write-delay-seconds>0</write-delay-seconds>
        </map-store>
        <entry-listeners>
            <entry-listener include-value="true" local="false">models.hazelcast.listeners.TestListener</entry-listener>
        </entry-listeners>  

        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>
    </map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you do all of the following to debug and hopefully fix

1. run jstatd on the server where the hazelcast server is running (e.g.)
   jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy -J-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

then attach jvisualvm to figure out what's going on with your server application.  You can also use top for basic info on the process.

2. Share how you are starting your java process - how much memory do you have available on the server.  What are the Xms and Xmx values for the java process that you are specifying.
3. Try using G1GC - if simply changing step2 does not solve your problem.
4. If steps2 and steps3 do not work, try adding more servers to the server cluster.
5. Does this happen right after when you run the server or after running for a while - is the memory usage changing based on how your application works?

Comment: I increased Xms and Xmx as well as switched to G1GC and the issue seems to have gone away.  TOP shows almost 90% memory usage.  So either I need to reduce the data in-memory or add more nodes.